# Azure Devops: How to pass variable FROM agent job TO agentless job?

Tags: azure-devops, cicd

I have a pipeline with 2 jobs.

1. CheckoutAndDeploy (standard agent job)
2. WaitDeployStatus (agentless)

In WaitDeployStatus (1) I am trying to use an agentless job with [Invoke Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops). In this step, I need to post on an URL, the URL requires OAuth authentication

I can get the OAuth token from the previous job (CheckoutAndDeploy) and set isOutput=true to make the var available for other jobs ([like described in the documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/outputvariable.md)) but I am unable to use it in job 2.

I already tried:

```
 $(SOMEREF.ACCESS_TOKEN)"
 $[ dependencies.Get_Access_Token.outputs['SOMEREF.ACCESS_TOKEN'] ]"
 $[ dependencies.Get_Access_Token.CheckoutAndDeploy.outputs['SOMEREF.ACCESS_TOKEN'] ]"
 $[ stageDependencies.CheckoutAndDeploy.outputs['SOMEREF.ACCESS_TOKEN'] ]"
```

To set the variable is a bash task with this code:

```
TOKEN_RESQUEST=$(command_to_get_the_token)
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ACCESS_TOKEN;isOutput=true]$TOKEN_REQUEST"
```

Then I use SOMEREF as a reference name to access the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below usage will be able to pass the runtime variables from agent job to agentless job:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: A #agent job
  steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "A"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputVar;isoutput=true]<Auth information here>"
    name: passOutput
- job: B #agentless job
  pool: server
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['passOutput.outputVar'] ]  
  steps:
    - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
        serviceConnection: 'GetProjects'
        method: 'GET'
        headers: |
          {
          "Content-Type":"application/json",  
          "Authorization": "$(myVarFromJobA)"
          }
        waitForCompletion: 'false'
```

Auth passed, I can successfully get the results here:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention, I use classic pipeline mode.